# problem with android : data from class don't send to activity

Tags: java, android

i wrote the code to an activity it work perfect but when i writhing them to a java class and send the result to the activity is not show anything to text view.

```
public class TheaudiodbWebData  {

    private String result = "";

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }


    public TheaudiodbWebData() {
        getBiographyData();
    }

    private void getBiographyData() {
        String url = "https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=coldplay";
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                parseBiographyData(responseString);
            }
        });
    }

    private void parseBiographyData(String response) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            TheaudiodbArtistBio bio = gson.fromJson(response, TheaudiodbArtistBio.class);
            result = bio.getArtists().get(0).getStrArtist();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

and this is the Activity code :

```
public class BiographyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_biography);
        test=findViewById(R.id.test);

        TheaudiodbWebData bio=new TheaudiodbWebData();
        test.setText(bio.getResult());
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you set the data in the TheaudiodbWebData class and then want to move that to another activity and that is not working?
Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: yes is correct and is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not passing data from one `Activity` to another `Activity` and you are getting the result than problem is clear. Part of code which you are executing in `onCreate()` method:

```
TheaudiodbWebData bio=new TheaudiodbWebData();
test.setText(bio.getResult());
```

is executed immediately but you are getting results over the Internet which means that data is not received immediately *(connecting server -> getting result -> returning result = takes some time)* that is why you have `callback` methods `onFailure` and `onSuccess` which are triggered after result is returned from the Internet depending was it successful or fail.

So solution is to create your own `interface` with method where you can pass the result than implement that interface and create your own `callback` methods.

Or more simpler solution move this part of code directly into your `Activity` and set the the result to the `TextView` in `onSucces` method for example:

```
private void getBiographyData() {
String url = "https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=coldplay";
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
        test.setText(responseString);
     }
  });
}
```

After that simply call this method inside `onCreate()` like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_biography);
  test=findViewById(R.id.test);

  getBiographyData();

 }
```

Comment: oh thanks , but i want to load all data from this webservice to a class and send result to 3 separated Activities so what's your suggestion

Comment: @Hossein obtain data in one `Activity` and pass it to another using `Intent` I will update the code.